# Magento 2 - Is it possible update payment method of order programmatically?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment-methods

Is there a way to update payment method of order in magento 2 via dependency Injector or Object factory without using raw sql query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load `order` instance either from order `entity_id` or `increment_id`. After that, try these code. I haven't tested these code

```
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$payment->setMethod('yourpaymentmethodcode');
$payment->save();
$order->save();
```

or

```
$order->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'yourpaymentmethodcode']);
$order->save();
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: this one doesn't return the `name` of assigned payment method in `customer.orders` query for some reason